# What module should a Data Service belong to? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have 3 modules in my application. The main module and two feature modules (customer and invoice). I defined a 'CustomerService' to retrieve data from a REST api. This service is defined inside the 'app.customer' module and is used in the 'CustomerListController' of the same module for showing a list of customers.

Now, I use the same 'CustomerService' in my 'InvoiceEditController' of the invoice module to populate a dropdown for the user when creating an invoice.

```
angular.module('app', ['app.customer','app.invoice']);

angular.module('app.customer', ['ngResource'])
.factory('CustomerService', ['$resource',
     function($resource) {
         return $resource('http://rest.com/customers/:id');
     }
])
.controller('CustomerListController', ['$scope', 'CustomerService',
     function($scope, CustomerService) {
         $scope.customers = CustomerService.get();
     }
]);

angular.module('app.invoice', []);
.controller('InvoiceEditController', ['$scope', 'CustomerService',
     function($scope, CustomerService) {
         $scope.customers = CustomerService.get();
     }
]);
```

Should the CustomerService be grouped inside the app.customer module or should I create a new module and group data service providers together (e.g: CustomerService, ProductService, InvoiceService into an app.services module)?

The reason for the latter may be because you want to isolate the dependencies. That is, a controller may not need the 'ngResource' module as a dependency while the service will.

However, grouping the services together will result in the module having services from different features (which may be unrelated with one another).

What's the current guideline for this?

Comment: It's an opinion thing.  I would expect a CustomerService to be in a customer module.

Answer (score 1):

Well I believe that it is very related to the problem you are trying to solve. In my opinion services are common to the application because as you mentioned they can be reused in several features of your application and what is more they can be potentially used in the future by other features. So I would suggest to create a new module called "Common" and put the services in there.

Hope it helps.
Cheers!